# How to get all images with custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have custom taxonomy `location` for all attachments and trying to list all images with `location == background` like this:

```
foreach(get_posts(array('post_type' => 'attachment')) as $image) {
    foreach(wp_get_post_terms($image->ID, 'location') as $term) {
        if ($term->slug == 'background') echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID);
    }
}
```

How i can do that in more simple way? Without extra loops and queries.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this (Using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/jpg,image/png',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'background'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        //...
    endwhile;
endif;
```